# Change table row if a textbox has a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am new to javascript and Jquery i have a table with 5 rows, and an asp slider that selects a value from 1 to 5. i want the corresponding row in the table to be highlighted when moving the slider. is this possible with javascript or Jquery please?

Comment: this is definitely possible, you could have an event on the slider that updates adds a highlight class to the table row in question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although I do not know anything about `.NET`, I do know how to implement this in JavaScript.

HTML5 introduces a new input type called `range`. The `input` element has an event listener called `change`, which looks for changes in the input's value.

To make things simple, I created a generic table with five rows. When the change event is fired, the specific row will be highlighted and other rows will be back to normal.

I'm sure this can be improved, but at the moment, this was the only thing I could come up with

You should use a similar approach for your object.

```js
var range = document.getElementById("my-range");
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

range.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var rowIndex = +(range.value) - 1;
    var irrelevant = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        irrelevant.push(i);
    }
    irrelevant = irrelevant.filter(function(e) {
        return e != rowIndex;
    });
    tableRows[rowIndex].style.background = "gold";
    tableRows[irrelevant[0]].style.background = "white";
    tableRows[irrelevant[1]].style.background = "white";
    tableRows[irrelevant[2]].style.background = "white";
    tableRows[irrelevant[3]].style.backgroudn = "white";
});
```

```html
<input id="my-range" type="range" min="1" max="5" />
  
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>R1 C1</td>
    <td>R1 C2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R2 C1</td>
    <td>R2 C2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R3 C1</td>
    <td>R3 C2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R4 C1</td>
    <td>R4 C2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R5 C1</td>
    <td>R5 C2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. As in http://jsfiddle.net/venuchitta/uuLfwtrw/

```js
$("#slider").slider(
{
            value:1,
            min: 1,
            max: 5,
            step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#slider-value" ).html( ui.value );
                 $('#data tr').removeClass('highlighted');
                 $('#data tr:eq('+(ui.value-1)+')').addClass('highlighted');
            }
}
);
```

```css
h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;   
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
}

body, p{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}
    
tr.highlighted td {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>HTML Slider Test</h1>

<div id="slider"></div>

<p>Your slider has a value of <span id="slider-value"></span></p>

<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" width="500" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the above, as i said new to java and jquery but eager to learn, when i copy the code above into my asp or even html page it does not appear to work just shows the code lines above and an empty table, am i missing something (suspect i am )! further background, the page is a slider that chooses answers from a table 1 -5 the number returned by the slider needs to be kept as a session variable for use later in the site (it is uploaded to a DB wiht other similar pages) the slider also needs to be vertical down the left side of the table. any further help greatly appreciated.

Comment: HI thanks yep can see it works in jsfiddle, but when I preview run it in my VS it shows a message of Object doesn't support property or method slider, do I need to load a different Jquery library? I am using native jquery-1.8.2 and have the base js and min..js loaded in my html file.

Comment: Hi there, - right got the slider to show and errors have gone (didn't rerefence the jsui css and was missin gthe js-ui script line.

Comment: but now when I move the slider the color doesn't change in the table rows so I am thinking I have my CSS entries in wrong place or location, can you advise please>? also if I want the slider to be vertical down left side of table same height as the table is this easy to accomplish? thanks.